# The import javax.microedition.contactless cannot be resolved

Tags: android, java-me, android-emulator

I try to run sample code but got some error:

`The import javax.microedition.contactless cannot be resolved`.

After some research I found that I need to add the jar file but unfortunately I could find the link to download the jar and attach to my project.

Appreciate if anyone could help me to provide the link.

Comment: are you developing a j2me application?

Comment: yes. Im trying to run sample code to read visual tags.

Comment: your question is tagged with android and android-emulator. Do you try this import with Android and android emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, then search device specification or JSR if api you are using supported by the particular device or not.

Comment: I googled but most the thing I found is the API spec. Couldnt find the API it self.